# How to grant permission for user in table where the id is his username (row permission read rethinkdb)

Tags: rethinkdb

Is it possible to grant permission for user in table, but only for a specific row in that table. I have a table named PrivateUserInfo where I store users' emails and nicknames: [image] 
 Granting permissions like that:
 `r.db('dbname').table('PrivateUserInfo').grant('testuser', {read: true});` 
allows them to read everyones data. I want to allow them to read only the row where the id is their username. Setuping a webserver to handle this type of things will defeat the purpose. If I am going to create a webserver then I wouldn't even use permissions in first place and just handle the requests with the web app logged as admin. Which I really want to avoid. This was the main reason I want to use this database.

Comment: it is not possible